# How to call one module sub inside another module sub in Perl

Tags: perl

I have created Perl modules under `/my_project/ABC/`. The `ABC` folder contains three subroutine modules: `Build.pm`, `Config.pm`, and `Operation.pm`. There is a common subroutine in `Operation.pm` that I need to access from `Config.pm`, but when I tried i throws

> "configureTheRepository" is not exported by the ABC::Config module`.

Here is the call stack.

#### Operation.pm

```
    package ABC::Operation;

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);
    use File::Basename qw(dirname);
    use Exporter qw(import);
    use Term::ANSIColor qw( colored );
    use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
    use JSON::PP;
    use File::Basename qw(dirname);
    use Cwd  qw(abs_path);
    use ABC::Config qw(configureTheRepository);

    our @EXPORT = qw(commonFunc)

   sub commonFunc{
      #handle logic
    }
1;
```

#### Config.pm

```
    package ABC::Config;

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);
    use File::Basename qw(dirname);
    use Exporter qw(import);
    use Cwd  qw(abs_path);
    use Cwd  qw(abs_path);
    use ABC::Operation qw(commonFunc); #Compilation failed when i insert this line.if i removed this my script will execute and but in runtime throws undefined commonFunc.

   our @EXPORT = qw(configureTheRepository);

   sub configureTheRepository{
      #handle logic
    }

1;
```

Please let me know where I made the mistake.

Comment: Comments in Perl are done with `#`, not `//`. That's an empty regular expression pattern.

Comment: Is there an Exporter or any other exporting mechanism in Operation.pm? It doesn't export just because you've declared an `@EXPORT`.

Comment: @simbabque no but using that way i can call `Config subs` inside my `Operation.pm`

Comment: I don't believe that. Your `use ABC::Config` actually calls `ABC::Config->import`. If you do not have an `import` sub in there, it cannot import anything. The `@EXPORT` is not something Perl has by default, it's an interface defined by Exporter, which you would typically use as a base class for your module. So this cannot work. Show your real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a circular dependency. `use` statements get done at *compile time*. That means before any actual code is run. So when you start your program, and the first thing it does is go into `ABC::Operation`, the following will happen:

- scan ABC::Operation for `use` statements
- load Term::ANSIColor

  - parsing switches to Term::ANSIColor
  - scan Term::ANSIColor for `use` statements ...
- parsing switches back to ABC::Operation
- load File::Basename

  - parsing switches to File::Basename
  - scan File::Basename
- parsing switches back to ABC::Operation
- ... a couple more of those
- load ABC::Config

  - parsing switches to ABC::Config
  - scan ABC::Config for `use` statements ...
- parsing witches back to ABC::Operation

  - `import` stuff from Term::ANSIColor, File::Basename, Exporter and Cwd; these do not get loaded again because Perl already loaded them before. It only imports the symbols into the current ABC::Config namespace
  - `import` the function `commonFunc` from ABC::Config; again, this has also already been loaded, so it doesn't load it again
  - throw an error because at this point, ABC::Config has not finished parsing, and it does not yet export a `commonFunc` symbol

This is a bit confusing, but it's a sign that your architecture is broken. If things are common, they can sure be in a common package. But that common package **cannot** use anything that uses it. If that's the case, whatever is using it also becomes common by definition.

The solution is to rethink which functions go where. Find the smallest possible parts, and put them in one package. That's the things every other package shares. Then use it where it's needed. The next things that use this shouldn't bring each other in. Only the last level should combine all of them. The dependency tree is called tree for a reason. Having a circle in there can't work.

Comment: thanks.i created a CommonUtils package and put shared code there and it worked.